# Generate ramp audio signal of frequencies within specific duration

Tags: matlab, audio

I wanted to generate frequencies of 10hz to 1000hz with a step of 10hz, let's say within 5s (all frequencies equally distributed within the time frame). How do I achieve this from the individual frequency generator function below?

```
function [ ] = producefeq( frequency, duration, amplitude, freqsampling )

if ~exist('freqsampling', 'var'), freqsampling = 44100; end
if ~exist('amplitude', 'var'), amplitude = 1; end
if nargin <2, error('Not enough input arguments'); end

% the frequency argument will be like this for the case above 10:10:1000

t = 0:(1/freqsampling):duration;
y = amplitude*sin(2*pi*frequency*t);
sound(y, freqsampling);

end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can call `producefeq` multiple times and use `pause` to wait between multiple executions.

```
totalDuration = 500;
frequencies = 10:10:1000;
duration = totalDuration/length(frequencies);

for i = 1:length(frequencies)
    producefeq( frequencies(i), duration)
    pause(duration)
end
```